# Is the expression "ut poësis pictura" formally correct?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, grammar-choice

I'm writing an essay in which I'd like to use the expression "*ut poësis pictura*" with the intent of flipping the original expression by Horace "*ut pictura poësis*". I never studied Latin so I'm asking if using this formula is formally correct.

More precisely I intend to use the expression according to the following logic (with my tentative translation):

ORIGINAL: *ut pictura poësis*: as it is in painting should be in poetry

REINVENTED: *ut poësis pictura*: as it is in poetry should be in painting

Is this correct? Does this makes sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quote of Horace is the beginning of De arte poetica v. 361; the scansion is: - x - uu - u (where "x" is the replacement of an uu by an -). The reversement of the word order wpuld destroy the hexameter. BTW, the length of the e in poesis is due to the Eta in the underlying greek word ποίησις.

Comment: Yep, as a motto of sorts, you can reverse them with no other change in grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ut poesis pictura* literally means 'as poetry, [so] painting'. Since both nouns occupy the same syntactic spot, it is semantically and grammatically sound to reverse the phrase to *ut pictura poesis* 'as painting, [so] poetry'.

And, logically, it is a tautological necessity that, if *ut poesis pictura,* so too *ut pictura poesis.*